# Multiple Json's for retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, pojo

I am using Retrofit 2 and the json that i am getting back if its a successful call looks something like this

```
{
 a:123,
 b:456,
 c:789
 }
```

But when there is an error being returned from the server the error json looks like

`{
  error:"Error Message"
 }`

The error here is not an error in the connection,the call completed successfully.How do i configure retrofit to process this so i know if i received the first json or the second and display a message accordingly.

Comment: You need to design your API better to tell you when there is a success with data, or an error with a message

Comment: Sadly more often then not we don't have control over apis we need to use, so we have to deal with them :(
For me this is not even a bad design :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BaseResponse class and the rest of your responses class inherits from this class.

For example:

```
public class BaseResponse implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("error")
    public String error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need model something like:

```
public class Example {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    @Nullable public String error;

    public boolean isError() {
        return error != null && !error.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

and then in retrofit callback just check

```
Example example = response.body();
if (example.isError) {
    // show error message
} else {
    // show successfull response
}
```